# get chunk from a very large file without reading previous lines

Tags: io

I got a very large file, like:

```
c,c,c,c
v,v,v,v
v,v,v,v
.
.
.
v,v,v,v # line number 10000000
.
.
.
```

I need to read line 10000000, how can I get it without iterate previous lines?

Is there anything like a pointer/address to access it directly?

Comment: If every line is the same length, then yes, you can just seek to byte 9*10000000 (or maybe 8*... if the line endings are just `\n`?). How you do that depends on what programming language you're using, but if you search for "seek" and that language, you'll probably find it.

Comment: @smarx great answer, thank you so much!